# Cannot get dovecot SASL to work with postfix

Tags: ubuntu, debian, postfix, email-server, dovecot

Running debian 6, I believe I've enabled everything correctly, followed various guides to double check as I've been working on this for 3 days now. I've tested both dovecot and postfix with telnet and they work as best as I can tell, however I'm not getting the expected SASL support response when using smtp. I don't really know how to troubleshoot it further than that.

Also fwiw I noticed that dovecot -n outputs mode as set to 432 where as it's actually set to 0660 in dovecot.conf, any idea why this is, might this be related?

dovecot.conf

```
# 1.2.15: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-238.9.1.el5.028stab089.1 x86_64 Debian 6.0.4 
log_timestamp: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S 
protocols: imap imaps pop3 pop3s
login_dir: /var/run/dovecot/login
login_executable(default): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
login_executable(imap): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
login_executable(pop3): /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
mail_privileged_group: mail
mail_location: mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mbox_write_locks: fcntl dotlock
mail_executable(default): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
mail_executable(imap): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
mail_executable(pop3): /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
mail_plugin_dir(default): /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/imap
mail_plugin_dir(imap): /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/imap
mail_plugin_dir(pop3): /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/pop3
auth default:
  mechanisms: plain login
  passdb:
    driver: pam
  userdb:
    driver: passwd
  socket:
    type: listen
    client:
      path: /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
      mode: 432
      user: postfix
      group: postfix
```

main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = fresno.thinkitrva.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = thinkitrva.com
mydestination = thinkitrva.com, fresno.thinkitrva.com, localhost.thinkitrva.com, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
relay_domains = thinkitrva.com

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
# Can be an absolute path, or relative to $queue_directory
# Debian/Ubuntu users: Postfix is setup by default to run chrooted, so it is best to leave it as-is below
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
# and the common settings to enable SASL:
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#anti-spam: smpt restrictions
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sals_authenticated

smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
        reject_unknown_helo_hostname

smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net
```

Comment: For one thing, you can check logs. Both Dovecot and Postfix do output lines to `syslog` when they do authentication. As for the socket mode appearing in decimal instead of octal in the `dovecot -n` output, there's no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

You should never run *just* SASL on a public server.

Either enable *both* TLS and SASL for incoming mail, or - better - configure the commented-out **submission** listener in master.cf, and tell people to use that.

Please refer to the [**excellent**](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#server_enable) [**documentation**](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_dovecot) for further details.

Comment: I was not planning to, but I first have to setup SASL before TLS so if I cannot get SASL working no point moving to TLS, no? The postfix documentation is the primary thing I was following, along with the linked dovecot documentation (in the postfix article).

Comment: "Have to"? No. You can enable both at the same time, with a fixed set of configuration parameters.